# Vue-router page refresh or URL access

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a landing page with register/login from that redirects to main page with content. After successful login I redirect like this:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'main' })
```

And this works, but if I refresh the page or try to access it from url for example like http://testapp.test/main I get error: Page does not exists 404.
Currently I don’t have any protection against access to pages that are only for logged in users, I also added ‘*’ path in router for undefined routes and it also just throws 404 instead of loading home page. Here are my router settings:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import {store} from './store/store'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

window.Vue = require('vue');


import Home from './components/LandingPage.vue'
import Main from './components/MainPage.vue'
import Logout from './components/Logout.vue'

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home,
        },
        {
            path: '/main',
            name: 'main',
            component: Main,
        },
        {
            path: '/logout',
            name: 'logout',
            component: Logout,
        },
        {
            path :'*',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home,
        }
    ],
});


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { Home, Main, Logout },
    router,
    store,
});
```

I tried with https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations but I am not sure if I did it right. What I did is copied code for apache configuration and replaced existing code in .htaccess with it. But then even route from login stops working and if I access /main it gives me 404 error.

Comment: You shouldn't use the Home component for the path `*`. Just create like in the link you added a NotFoundComponent component or something like that which display to the user a 404 error.

Comment: That doesn't have anything with my problem acutally, because /main does exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with adding

```
Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () { return view('welcome'); })->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

into the web.php file

Answer (score 0):

You have to made also server side configuration for this.. As an alternative, you can try other router modes? like "hash"

Here is documentation for mode and server configuration.

https://router.vuejs.org/api/#mode

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: I already changed .htaccess as stated in post (used your second link). And hash method does work, but that's not what I am looking for